# Getting "more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'" when running wear module

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, build.gradle

I'm adding a wear module to an app. (using [this sample code](https://github.com/gdgbogota/codelab-synchronized-notifications) as a reference)

So I have 3 modules, each one depends on a version of com.google.android.gms:play-services:

1. app - compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
2. wear - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
3. shared - compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'

When compiling the Wear module, I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>     However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Obviously, if I change play-services-wearable play-services in the wear module's build.gradle, everything works fine, however from what I understand, play-services-wearable is a light-weight version of play-services.

Is there a way, considering my app's structure, to use play-services-wearable in my wear module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is more that you have multiple different versions of Google Play Services being used within the same app (version 6.1 and version 6.5). You can update your shared (and app) modules to use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+` and then you'll only have one version of Google Play Services and avoid the issue you are facing.

In your case, you only need to define Google Play Services in the shared module - assuming your app and wear modules both have a dependency on it, they'll automatically inherit any dependencies so redeclaring them is unnecessary (although it doesn't harm things if you prefer to do it anyways).

Note: the `play-services-wearable` library is one of the many [split libraries](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) available in Google Play Services 6.5 - these do indeed allow you to only include the parts of Google Play Services you need in your application. In almost all cases, you should consider moving to explicitly depending on only the parts of Google Play Services rather than using `com.google.android.gms:play-services` in its entirety: by including the entire `com.google.android.gms:play-services` even once you pull in all of Google Play services even if later you declare or use a single portion of the library.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! If I will add the full Google Play Services module only to my shared module, wouldn't the main and wear modules (which depend on the shared module) each use contain the entire Play Services lib code? meaning, my wear module will include a lot more than it needs?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right, hence why I suggest not using the full Google Play Services dependency.

Comment: You may also look at this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775891/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-using-co/34776219#34776219