# Android, one library with old google play service conflicts with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm using asne google plus library for my project. It uses older version of google play service.

When I add Google maps with newer version, gradle build fails with this message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

My dependencies in my app.gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.3.3'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

When I make `asne` like this:

```
compile ('com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.3.3') {
  transitive = true
}
```

This lib becomes invisible and I can't call its methods.

How to resolve this conflict?

Comment: You cannot have two libraries with different versions work in one project. Try updating the play services library of the one that contains the old library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggests that you use the entire dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

and not split it into parts like play-services-location:8.3.0 and play-services-maps:8.3.0. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665105/getting-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-when) provides a detailed explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just exclude the google dependencies of the library:

```
compile ('com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.3.3') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Comment: OK gradle is compiled, but when I try to call `asne` method it throws me an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.gorbin.asne.googleplus.GooglePlusSocialNetwork`