# Searching Latlng inside Polygon is not precise

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to check if map centre is inside a polygon or not. My code for creating mulitple polygons on map is this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Constant.arr_zone.size(); i++) {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < Constant.arr_zone.get(i).polygon.length; j++) {
                list.add(new LatLng(Constant.arr_zone.get(i).polygon[j].geo_x,
                        Constant.arr_zone.get(i).polygon[j].geo_y));
                builder.include(list.get(j));

            }
            polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
            polygonOptions.addAll(list);
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(R.color.theme_color);
            polygonOptions.strokeWidth(2);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#33000040"));
            Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
            ltbounds = builder.build();
            arr_ltlngbounds.add(ltbounds);
        }
```

Next I am checking if map center is inside any polygon or not

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    if (arr_ltlngbounds != null && arr_ltlngbounds.size() > 0) {
                        for (LatLngBounds l : arr_ltlngbounds) {
                            if (l.contains(mMap.getCameraPosition().target)) {

                                snackbar = Snackbar
                                        .make(inflatedView, "Service available here", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                        .setAction("GET", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                                String arr[] = {user_location.latitude + "", user_location.longitude + "", "4"};
                                                new Get_service(activity, A.this, get_service).execute(arr);
                                            }
                                        });
                                snackbar.show();
                                break;
                         }
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my build.gradle just incase

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.aaa.bbb"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:v1.0.22'
compile 'com.xgc1986.android:parallaxpagertransformer:1.0.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev6-1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}


}
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.3.1"
}

}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
// for downloading polypicker dependency cwac-camera
maven {
    url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
}

// for downloading poly-picker now we are using jitpack.
// Goodbye Maven Central
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

The problem about this implementation is, it still shows snackbar (that latlng is inside bounds) even if latlng is outside bounds up to a certain level like there is some buffer area where it will still detect the latlng. I want it to be precise. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PolyUtil.containsLocation` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to check if a given location lies inside a polygon represented by a `List<LatLng>` instead of just checking if the location is in the boundary.

Example:

```
// Construct a List<LatLng> representing a Polygon
List<LatLng> polygon = new ArrayList<>();
polygon.add(new LatLng(3,0));
polygon.add(new LatLng(3,3));
polygon.add(new LatLng(0,3));
polygon.add(new LatLng(3,0));

// Find the LatLngBounds of the Polygon
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng point : polygon) {
    builder.include(point);
}

LatLng test = new LatLng(1,1);

boolean isInsideBoundary = builder.build().contains(test); // true as the test point is inside the boundary
boolean isInside = PolyUtil.containsLocation(test, polygon, true); // false as the test point is outside the polygon
```

Comment: While including library i am getting error:Error:Execution failed for task ':needToPark:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.maps.android'
  You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
  However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Comment: How are you including the library? To add it to your project just add `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'` to the `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle`

Comment: That is what i did. Still getting the same issue. I am trying to figure out why I am getting that error.  Added compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' in build.gradle

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665105/getting-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-when.
I would recommend to remove all the dependencies `com.google.android.gms:play-services*` and add the dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107009/discussion-between-victor-and-antonio).

Comment: I have removed all the dependencies having prefix com.google.android.gms: . I am still getting the same error. May be there is some other library with package name com.google.maps.android